# Convert MS Word Table To DataTable without using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, datatable, ms-word, office-interop

How to convert Word Table To C# DataTable without using  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. I have searched a lot but didn't find any solution.
Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: You should find this helpful. Need to modify it to meet your specific needs - https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-convert-Word-table-0cb4c9c3#content

Comment: @Yogi I have some text in between different tables due to which this solution is not working.

Comment: The only way to work with a Word document without the Word application is to leverage the Word Open XML. Starting point for that is the Open XML SDK 2.5, although there are other tools out there. But many of those don't support the entire "object model".

Answer (score -1):

There is no straight way for converting Word tables into data tables. But there are two main ways for getting the job done, i.e. reading a Word document's content:

1. Using any third-party components that don't require Office installed on the machine. For example, take a look at Aspose components.
2. Using the Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information. The SDK is built on the `System.IO.Packaging` API and provides strongly-typed classes to manipulate documents that adhere to the Office Open XML File Formats Specification. The Office Open XML File Formats specification is an open, international, ECMA-376, Second Edition and ISO/IEC 29500 standard. The Open XML file formats are useful for developers because they are an open standard and are based on well-known technologies: ZIP and XML.
   The Open XML SDK 2.5 simplifies the task of manipulating Open XML packages and the underlying Open XML schema elements within a package. The Open XML SDK 2.5 encapsulates many common tasks that developers perform on Open XML packages, so that you can perform complex operations with just a few lines of code.
   In that case you can deal only with Office Open XML File Formats.